# Microphone not working in earphone/microphone combo port on an HP 450-a12il desktop

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have an [HP 450-a12il desktop](http://support.hp.com/ph-en/document/c04719831).  This CPU has an earphone/mic combo jack on the front, but when I plug in a combo earphone, only the output works not the input. Is there a way to fix this. I am running Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score -2):

I think, this could be a issue because of driver. so you need to update the driver and check your computer. it will start working fine.

Comment: This may be true but we're looking for answers with a bit more detail. Why specifically do you think it's a driver issue?